# Slow 3D rotation with antialiasing in Mathematica 7

Tags: 3d, wolfram-mathematica, antialiasing

3D surface rotation in *Mathematica* 7 with anti-aliasing turned off is very fast and smooth.  However, turning on anti-aliasing, even at a moderate level, drastically reduces the rendered frame rate, making rotation very choppy.  This happens to a much greater degree in *Mathematica* than it does in other 3D applications.

1. Why is anti-aliasing disproportionately slower in *Mathematica*?
2. A way to greatly enhance the feel of 3D graphics would be to turn off AA during rotation, but turn it on as soon as rotation is stopped.  Can this be done in *Mathematica* 7?

---

An example was requested.  I will use a variation of Mike's code.  Please try the following with `Edit > Preferences > Appearance > Graphics` first set to `No antialiasing` and then `Highest quality`.  Also try the settings in between.  For me, any setting besides `No antialiasing` is not smooth.  I can visually distinguish three different levels of AA, so it is not a matter of my GPU forcing all or none, yet all of them are slow.

```
Animate[Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  ImageSize -> 700,
  ViewPoint -> 
   Dynamic[{Sin[theta] Cos[phi], Sin[theta] Sin[phi], Cos[theta]}]],
 {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi},
 RefreshRate -> 120
]
```

---

## UPDATE and OBSERVATION

While playing around with Alexey and Mike's code, something strange and good happened.  I suddenly have smooth antialiased rotation!  I don't know what precipitated the change, and I have not closed *Mathematica* for fear that it will go away, but this proves what I suspected, that it CAN be fast.

More strange, I have the slow and fast behavior happening *in parallel* in the same notebook.  One graphic is rotating smoothly, and another produced with the same code is choppy.  I theorize that some cell option was modified by running Alexey and Mike's code, and it is having a very desirable effect.  I am going to do my best to figure out what it is.

---

The helpful options were `RotationAction -> "Clip", SphericalRegion -> True` that appeared in Alexey's code incidentally.  These, or their effect (`ViewAngle`), "stick" with a graphic in the same way that rotation does, therefore I was able to type new code without these options over the old, and run it, and still get the smooth rotation (which explains what I saw above).  See answers below for some elaboration.

While a viable workaround has been discovered, I am still interested in an explanation for the choppy rotation with AA on.  I do not believe that the "fitting" of the graphic is an explanation, but merely a correlation, as the fitting still needs to take place with AA off, and yet the rotation is smooth.

Comment: I've noticed this as well. The only place I know where you can accomplish something vaguely similar is within `Manipulate`, through the use of `PerformanceGoal->Speed`.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Would you post an example?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: A *heisenbug* of sorts perhaps? Though in this case this seems to be an extremely desirable heisenbug.

Comment: **The speed difference survived a notebook save and mma restart.  It should be possible to pin down a difference.**

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Should I stick this in a new answer or keep it within my existing one? I just finished typing it up.

Comment: @Mike I say a new answer; I have already voted for your existing answer, and anything more that is helpful deserves another vote.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I've added my newest answer. I believe this should be the "end all" solution to the slow 3D graphics issues in Mathematica. If I had more votes, I'd vote this question up a few more times. This has been so helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appear to have discovered—for my configuration—a magic option that allows for smooth 3D rotation with full antialiasing on.  This works for every 3D plot type I have tried therefore unless this also magically stops working I have my solution.  I am very interested to know if this has the same effect on other systems.

The option is `ViewAngle`.  Any numeric value appears to work; `Automatic` does not.

Evaluating the code below the first graphic rotates poorly and the second graphic rotates smoothly.

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 900]

Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 900, ViewAngle -> 0.43]
```

---

I have a problem with Mike's `RotationAction -> "Clip"` method, in that I get unexpected and sometimes extreme cropping when rotate the graphic.  However, adding `SphericalRegion -> True` restores the behavior that I get with `ViewAngle`, and the angle is chosen automatically:

```
Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -2, +2}, {y, -2, +2}, 
 ImageSize -> 700, SphericalRegion -> True, RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

Comment: If I had to wager a guess, I'd bet it's because the default behavior has it automatically changing the bounds and resizing things. I'm going to do some testing to see if this is true.

Answer (score 7):

After Mr. Wizard pointed out that changing the ViewAngle improved performance, I had a hunch as to what was causing it.

Normally, when you rotate graphics in Mathematica, you'll notice the box that contains the graphics resizes itself as the image is rotated around. Why? Most of the settings are set to the default of `Automatic`, so they try to fiddle around to make the graphics fit nicely within the screen. Specifically, `Plot3D` (and many other 3D `Plot` functions) have a named parameter called `RotationAction`. According to the [Mathematica documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RotationAction.html?q=RotationAction&lang=en):

> 3D graphics by default resize and move to fit when they are interactively rotated

This parameter defaults to `RotationAction->"Fit"`, which tries to always make sure the entire 3D graphics fits on screen. Instead, you can force the graphics to clip using `RotationAction->"Clip"`. This causes the bounding box to remain the same. Instead of resizing, it merely chops off whatever goes off screen. Performance is improved *dramatically* as Mathematica doesn't have to continuously reshape the image to make everything fit on screen.

Example code:

```
Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -2, +2}, {y, -2, +2}, 
 ImageSize -> 700, RotationAction -> "Fit"]

Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -2, +2}, {y, -2, +2}, 
 ImageSize -> 700, RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

---

## Some further notes

Upon further analysis, `RotationAction->"Clip"` has some issues with rotation initially. On the very first rotation of the graphics, it rotates extremely fast. I don't know why this is so, only Wolfram Research could possibly answer that. After the initial rotation though, it rotates at the normal speed as any other graphics though.

The smoothest way of accomplishing nice rotation for me was given by:

```
 Plot3D[..., RotationAction -> "Clip", ViewAngle -> 0.4]
```

This is as close to the default clipping volume as possible, without any strange issues with fast rotations or cut off graphics.

Comment: I've spent entirely too much time this morning (It's 4:17 AM here!) on this.

Comment: Wolfram should seriously consider documenting the fact that this option can have a drastic effect on performance

Comment: Since you don't sleep I'll talk too. ;-)  First, I wonder why this only causes a major slowdown with AA turned on.  Second, I am getting weird behavior with your example above.  The one using `"Clip"` zooms in immediately and much too far as soon as I start rotating it.  I wonder if this is a bug, or if I have a conflicting configuration.

Comment: Strange, here I see no difference whatsoever in how smoothly the plots rotate (this is on OS X 10.7.1, on a macbook with pathetic integrated graphics; not a monster machine or anything)

Comment: @acl: Odd. On my laptop (2.16 GHz Core 2 Duo, and a crappy 8600M GS) the clipped version actually runs much faster for me. I also have AA set to the highest setting possible. Do you have it on the intermediate setting? I think it may not necessarily be GPU bound, since I see CPU usage spike whenever I rotate graphics on my laptop.

Comment: I have AA to highest. I tried changing and no difference (and I also see a CPU spike). Maybe I'll give it a try in a bigger, Linux machine, to see what will happen there. It may have to do with OS.

Comment: Mike, regarding your further notes, adding `ViewAngle -> 0.4` eliminates the "zoom" problem I am having, but it also makes `RotationAction` redundant; I can leave it out and get the same effect.  At this time I see no value to using `RotationAction`.  Good analysis, however.

Comment: @acl as evidenced by the smooth rotation with AA off and default settings, I propose that the choppiness is a bug.  Perhaps one that does not exist under OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Building off of Alexey's answer, I changed the code slightly so it doesn't modify the front end settings:

```
aa = True;
EventHandler[
 Style[
  Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -2, +2}, {y, -2, +2}, 
   ImageSize -> 700, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
   SphericalRegion -> True],
   Antialiasing -> Dynamic[aa, TrackedSymbols :> {aa}]],
 {"MouseUp" :> (aa = True), "MouseDown" :> (aa = False)}, 
 PassEventsDown -> True]
```

It accomplishes the same, but it avoids modifying $FrontEnd.

Here is a function which automatically tacks on the necessary logic for providing dynamically changing antialiasing:

```
Clear[DynamicAA]; (* Perhaps I should also add the HoldFirst attribute too, not sure *)
DynamicAA[graphics_] := Module[{aa},
  aa = True;
  EventHandler[
   Style[graphics, 
    Antialiasing -> Dynamic[aa, TrackedSymbols :> {aa}]], {"MouseUp" :> (aa = True), 
    "MouseDown" :> (aa = False)}, PassEventsDown -> True]]
```

Usage is what you what expect:

```
DynamicAA[Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 -y^2}, {x, -2, +2}, {y, -2, +2}, ImageSize->700]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not appear to be of help.  That is, with AA enabled, rotation is still very slow; this appears to be largely independent of the complexity of the surface.  It is easier to feel these effects with a larger graphic size.

Comment: I am not sure Why you need to add 'Dynamic' in the above after ViewPoint. Manipulate will update the plot3D each time theta or phi changes automatically?

Comment: Dynamic is added so it doesn't render the plot every time you adjust one of the sliders. I actually partially stole the idea from the documentation which used it for almost the same exact thing.

Comment: @Mike I do not see antialiasing with your code. The plot remains not antialiased irrespective to the global `$FrontEnd` setting.

Comment: @Alexey: I've fixed the code. I checked it on my laptop. I accidentally used `Rule` instead of `DelayedRule`. It should work fine now.

Comment: @Mike Now it works but for some reason rotation of the plot is very slow and choppy.

Comment: @Alexey: It could be that `Dynamic` is slower than the way you did things. I can't actually tell even with very large images (`ImageSize->1500`) on my desktop. Your code seems to run at about the same speed as my code on my end.

Comment: @Mike Rotation is choppy all the time when I am rotating the plot - `EventHandler` has already fired. It seems that `Dynamic` continues to update its value even when it is not necessary. May be it is possible to stop updating for this `Dynamic` via `EventHandler`?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps someone else can think of something clever with `Mouseover`. This works by displaying a different expression when the mouse is over the displayed object or not; try this to see:

```
Mouseover[
 Style[
  Graphics[Circle[]],
  Antialiasing \[Rule] True
  ],
 Style[
  Graphics[Circle[]],
  Antialiasing \[Rule] False
  ]
 ]
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how one would switch antialiasing on and off, nor do I know how to make something like `Plot[f,range,Option->Mouseover[1,2]]`.

The problem seems to be that `Mouseover` doesn't *evaluate* to different things when the cursor is/is not over it, but rather it *displays* different things--or so it looks.

Maybe someone who understands dynamic constructs better can work out how to use the infrastructure that lets `Mouseover` do its thing to solve your problem.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I have not been able to make it work with 3D.  The `$FrontEnd` option is `RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality"}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard To be more precise, it is `RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 0.}` for switching antialiasing off and `RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 1.}` for highest quality.

Comment: @Alexey, yes.  I guess I should have included that.

Comment: @acl: I like this answer a lot. I'm going to see what I can do to work `Dynamic` into this for a more usable solution.

Answer (score 3):

Based on acl's idea:

```
EventHandler[
 Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ImageSize -> 700, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
  SphericalRegion -> 
   True], {"MouseUp" :> (SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
     RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 1.}]), 
  "MouseClicked" :> (SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
     RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 1.}]), 
  "MouseDown" :> (SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
     RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 0.}])}, 
 PassEventsDown -> True]
```

You can see what happens with the option with:

```
Dynamic["HardwareAntialiasingQuality" /. 
  Last@Last@Options[$FrontEnd, RenderingOptions], 
 UpdateInterval -> .1]
```

How it works: it switches off antialiasing for the currend FrontEnd session when you rotate the plot and switches it on when you release the mouse. The only problem is that when the mouse is released and antialiasing is switched on, the FrontEnd does not render the graphics again to make it antialiased. The solution is to click the plot without rotating it - and it becomes antialiased!

Comment: I've edited my answer to have a slightly modified version of your code. I replaced your modification of `$FrontEnd` with a `Dynamic` and external variable giving the state of the antialiasing. Funnily enough, I was looking exactly at the documentation of `EventHandler` when I realized you posted this answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Interestingly, is there a way to force FrontEnd to re-render the graphics programmatically without clicking on it?

Comment: @Mike, Alexey, see my updated question.  There is something interesting happening.

Comment: Alexey, whether you knew it or not, your combination of `RotationAction -> "Clip"` and `SphericalRegion -> True` is the solution in itself.